# How to get a subarray?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a array, with a sub-array, i need to get the sub-array(Task ID), how i can get it?

[image: array, with a sub-array]

```
onDeleteTask(Id: string) {
  this._taskService.deleteTask(Id).subscribe(data => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.Notes.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.Notes[i].Tasks.filter(this.Notes.findIndex(e => e.Id === Id)));
    }
  });
}
```

Data:

```
[
   {
      "Id":"099c3d99-8f49-4298-934c-1fc5280d6d84",
      "Description":"12312",
      "NoteId":"1a91f108-e869-4427-ab5e-09d2262bfe20",
      "NoteTitle":"SAKI SAKI 5 DOOLLAA"
   },
   {
      "Id":"e74455d5-5002-4ea3-9f58-653440887690",
      "Description":"1",
      "NoteId":"1a91f108-e869-4427-ab5e-09d2262bfe20",
      "NoteTitle":"SAKI SAKI 5 DOOLLAA"
   },
   {
      "Id":"e75d537e-fe97-4dd5-8ca3-9cce5d3a1827",
      "Description":"2",
      "NoteId":"1a91f108-e869-4427-ab5e-09d2262bfe20",
      "NoteTitle":"SAKI SAKI 5 DOOLLAA"
   }
]
```

I tried this, but id doesn't work

Comment: Can you paste that Notes json here

Comment: @NagaSaiA   [{"Id":"099c3d99-8f49-4298-934c-1fc5280d6d84","Description":"12312","NoteId":"1a91f108-e869-4427-ab5e-09d2262bfe20","NoteTitle":"SAKI SAKI 5 DOOLLAA"},{"Id":"e74455d5-5002-4ea3-9f58-653440887690","Description":"1","NoteId":"1a91f108-e869-4427-ab5e-09d2262bfe20","NoteTitle":"SAKI SAKI 5 DOOLLAA"},{"Id":"e75d537e-fe97-4dd5-8ca3-9cce5d3a1827","Description":"2","NoteId":"1a91f108-e869-4427-ab5e-09d2262bfe20","NoteTitle":"SAKI SAKI 5 DOOLLAA"}]
thats incoming json code from http request

Comment: what the heck is goin on with that filter

Comment: out your data in your question by editing your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to get Id for the first occurance then:

```
this._taskService.deleteTask(Id).subscribe(data => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.Notes.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.Notes[i].Tasks[0].Id);
    }
  });
```

if you want to get all the Id's then

```
this.Notes[i].Tasks.map(task => task.Id);
```

Comment: I'm sending delete request to the server, and i need refresh my array after that, in another way i have to reload my page to see changes

Comment: what you are just saying is not related with your question. If your intention is to get Id's then you can use above approach. If you have any other question (which I believe unrelated with this) you can open new question.

Comment: you can read  [SO How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). hope it helps.

Comment: If my answer is relevant to your question please check it as Answer by clicking green tick.

Answer (score 0):

your `filter` method isn't being called correctly:

`this.Notes[i].Tasks.filter(this.Notes.findIndex(e => e.Id === Id))`

`filter` accepts a predicate method to run over each element of the array and should return a boolean, but `findIndex` returns a number or undefined. You're passing the result of `findIndex` to `filter`, so essentially you're doing `Tasks.filter(2)`, which doesn't make sense.

I'd offer a suggestion on how to fix it, but I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do with the array.

Comment: i just trying to find in subarray element by id, and then delete it